# Получить файл через 'php://input'

Tags: php

Отправляю файлы (избражение, изображние в архиве) на сервер POST-запросом. Файл приходит(данные появляются в $_FILES).

Но принять файлы нужно через функцию:

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Но функция ничего не возвращает.

Данный участок кода встречается в файлах обработчиках выгрузки из 1С, принимает архив который отправляет 1С. И там он успешно работает. Но в моём случает работать отказывается.

Comment: https://onfor.info/php-otpravka-file_get_contents-cherez-post/

Comment: Опишите вопрос подробнее.

Comment: работайте с `SOAP` протоколом, и тогда сможете принять через `php://input`, а иначе дохлый номер.

Comment: @And SOAP совсем не обязателен. Просто PHP если видит multipart/form-data, то парсит запрос сам и не предоставляет доступ к телу запроса.

Answer (score 0):

В [мануале](https://php.net/manual/ru/wrappers.php.php) об этом сказано:

> php://input недоступен с типом содержимого
>   enctype="multipart/form-data"

Обойти можно используя другой content-type, но это значит, что отправку надо будет делать самому (стандартная форма не годится).

UPD Пример отправки из js

index.php:

```
<?php

// php -S 127.0.0.1:8080

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']?? null;
if ($method === 'POST') {
    $body = file_get_contents('php://input');
    if ( ! empty($body)) {
        file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/file', $body);
        http_response_code(201);
        exit(0);
    } else {
        http_response_code(400);
        exit(1);
    }
} else {
    require __DIR__ . '/form.phtml';
}
```

form.phtml:

```
<form id="form" action="" method="POST">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<script>
    var form = document.querySelector('#form');
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var fileInput = event.target.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
        var file = fileInput.files[0];

        if (file) {
            var rq = new XMLHttpRequest();
            rq.open(
                event.target.getAttribute('method'),
                event.target.getAttribute('action')
            );
            rq.onload = function() {
                alert('Ok');
            };
            rq.onerror = function() {
                alert('Fail');
            };
            rq.send(file);
        } else {
            alert('Не выбран файл');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Этот момент я видел. Отправлял также `zip` архив с типом `application/zip`

Comment: @Stark причём здесь zip? Если используете форму и указываете `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, то `php://input` будет пустой.

Answer (score -1):

Это должно сработать.

```
$fp= fopen("1.txt","w"); 
if (fwrite($fp, file_get_contents('php://input'))) { 
    echo 'Success';
} else { 
    echo 'Error';
}  
fclose($fp);
```

Но если внимательно почитать документацию, то у php://input есть ограничение по директиве *allow_url_include*. Подробнее: [здесь](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include)